# Fullscreen Problem on flex,flash

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have problem with a fullscreen Flash video. I made a custom Flash video player. This video player is working properly on its own in fullscreen. When I use this player for swf in a Flex app, then fullscreen causes some trouble. The player always stretches the parent Flex container.

I have attached screenshots of the normal state and problem state

[NORMAL STATE http://122.183.225.85/images/full_video.JPG](http://122.183.225.85/images/full_video.JPG)
[Fullscreen state http://122.183.225.85/images/full_image.JPG](http://122.183.225.85/images/full_image.JPG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what the issue is, but if it's basically that your video is scaling in FULL_SCREEN, you need to disable the video expanding when you're viewing in FULL_SCREEN using this:

```
your_video.fullScreenTakeOver = false;
```

Comment: I found answer for it.I set the application width and height according to stageWidth and stageHeight in flex app.Anyway thanks for ur answer.